Backup email from IMAP to POP3 with Docker Container?
How can I download email messages off an IMAP server directly into a folder on an email client ?
I'm using a Synology NAS Mail Plus which I want to create folders for each email account, then take emails off a server and download it to Mail plus which I know is POP3. Which is essentially a back up of all the email accounts and servers.
I've done my research on GitHub and found a few, not many some are defunct which do such a thing. I'm hoping there is someone who has done this exact thing which can I help me as to a docker container which does this ?

Which email client? Found a few what on Github? Why Docker Container? Explaining the reason why you wish to use Docker may help clarify your request. Also note that we do not accept questions asking that we recommend existing products, software, hardware, or services. Right now your question has a bit of that flavor. I recommend that you read the HELP section to better understand this site, how it works, and what is and is not on topic, and then edit your post to focus it to your situation and make the request within the bounds of this site.

The email client which I want the emails to be backed too is Mail Plus; it's on the Synology NAS DSM software.
I've found a few docker containers that can do this IMAP type backup on GitHub, one of them is dovecot, the other I'm in conversation with the author of the tool, so far though no answer has been given for the other IMAP type backup by the author.
The reasoning for a docker container is that it's easier to update and manager especially on a NAS.
